# In Neural Networks and deep neural networks what does label-dropout mean

Tags: classification, neural-network, deep-learning, terminology, dropout

If you take the following sentence from an article on deep neural networks

> to regularize the classifier layer by estimating the marginalized effect of **label-dropout** during training.

What does label-dropout mean

Comment: For understanding that, you must understand what a drop out mean.  [This](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~hinton/absps/JMLRdropout.pdf) would help you with that :)

Comment: Care to help explain drop out

Answer (score 2):

I ended up finding [the paper you were referencing](https://www.cv-foundation.org/openaccess/content_cvpr_2016/papers/Szegedy_Rethinking_the_Inception_CVPR_2016_paper.pdf), maybe next time, add it to your post.

From what I can understand in this paper, *label-dropout* means that you are *dropping* the real labels and replace them with others.

The section of the paper you're referring to is explaining everything in great detail, so I'd try to read it carefully. In short, instead of using the ground-truth distribution (i.e. one 1 and a bunch of 0s) in the target layer, they are adding some uncertainty. That way, the model becomes less confident, and therefore is less prone to overfitting and becomes more adaptable.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it means groundtruth just keep one correct label while dropping out others. And this can cause some side-effects under extreme circumstances.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).